# c# class being overridden and can not be assigned

Tags: c#, class, reference, clone, variable-assignment

I am having a code like this

```
[System.Serializable] public class class1 {
    [System.Serializable] public class class2 {
        public int var1, var2; public string var3;
        public class2 () {}
        public class2 (int v1, int v2, string v3) {
            var1 = v1;
            var2 = v2;
            var3 = v3;
        }
    }
    public class2[] list;
}
public class1 _class1;
public void Assign () {
    _class1 = new class1 ();
    _class1.list = new class1.class2[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        _class1.list[i] = new class1.class2((int)Random.Range (10,20), (int)Random.Range (100,200), ((int) Random.Range(50, 75)).ToString ());
    }

}
```

this code i also connected with other scripts, which reads from here the values, but what i get is that

_class1.list[] all the objects inside this are frozen, i cannot change their value, i change thevalue and they got setted up again 0.

i use a code like this to copy

```
//inside class1
public static class1 copy (class1 tocopy) {
    class1 copy = new class1 ();
    copy.list = tocopy.list;
    return copy;
}
public class1 copy () {
    return class1.copy (this);
}

//inside class2
public static class2 copy (class2 tocopy) {
    class2 copy = new class2 ();
    copy.var1 = tocopy.var1;
    copy.var2 = tocopy.var2;
    copy.var3 = tocopy.var3;
    return copy;
}
public class2 copy () {
    return class2.copy (this);
}
```

even doing this, i get a class which is linked with that classX copy = new classX ();

and when i try to assign the value to this, it instantly reassigns the value it had when generated a copy.

i am doing this because when i was not using copy () it was making all the values of the list with the same last value, i was going to change the value of 1, and it was applied on all, they had a instance, a clone, i don't know how to call, a reference.

I don't know how to delete this reference that now i am referencing a new object, so now i have not reference with that class, so its better, it does not assign the values to the class which i copied. but i get the problem that i can't assign this.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. What are you then asking for?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see if your list contains the same object many times? If you add a unique identifier like a [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid) to each class (e.g. add `string guid = new Guid().ToString();` as a field in each class) then override the [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring) method to return that string, it'll make it a bit easier.

Comment: '[System.Serializable] public class class1 {
  [System.Serializable] public class class2 {
   public int var1, var2; public string var3;
   public class2 () {}
   public class2 (int v1, int v2, string v3) {
    var1 = v1;
    var2 = v2;
    var3 = v3;
   }
  }
  public class2[] list;
 }
 public class1 _class1;
 public void Assign () {
  _class1 = new class1 ();
  _class1.list = new class1.class2[3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
   _class1.list[i] = new class1.class2((int)Random.Range (10,20), (int)Random.Range (100,200), ((int) Random.Range(50, 75).ToString ()));
  }
 }'

Comment: i got it compiled, but in each case this is not the fully code, because it has more then 1000 lines, this is just a kiddy version of it.

Comment: i tried guid, it prints me "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

Comment: @patrickBoardley - Whoops. I meant `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

Comment: 29b744cb-1f26-43c2-81ad-95ec43a6af3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions is not very clear but I think that the problem is because you are making just a shallow copy, try changing `class1.copy` to copy every item of list:

```
public static class1 copy (class1 tocopy) {
    class1 copy = new class1 ();
    copy.list = new class1.class2[tocopy.list.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < tocopy.list.Length; i++) {
        copy.list[i] = tocopy.list[i].copy();
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but also tried that, but the problem is that [class1].copy ().list[i] can not be assigned, i try to assign, and it instantly clears the value, and resets the previous one

Comment: Are you actually invoking `Assign`?

Comment: i do, but this is just a kidding version of the full 1000 codeline plus code. i say that there are no overloads, (something which everyframe assign 0), i tried everything but nothing stops it to clear the value, as the class is countinuesly being setted from it s reference.is there any way to get it s reference?

Comment: You could actually work with pointers using unsafe code in C# as described in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx, but i doubt that would fix the problem.

Without more context it's very difficult to help you further.

Comment: ya, no in this case i was not using pointers, but i found to resolve my problem by doing loop and copy () each element.